# Unable to establish connection with the BluetoothHidDevice profile to a Windows 10 PC

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, hid

I'm attempting to write an app that connects to another device via bluetooth, identify itself as a keyboard via the new [`BluetoothHidDevice`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHidDevice) and then send text and/or single characters to the target device as keyboard input.

So far I got everything to work except establishing the bluetooth connection from my Huawei P10 to a Windows 10 laptop. It seems to work fine when connecting to another Android device when I tested it with a Galaxy S8+ on the receiving end, when I tried to establish a connection the P10 got correctly detected as a physical keyboard and I could send keyboard inputs to the S8+

I also tried it with two different laptops, one with a built-in bluetooth adapter and another with an external usb adapter, in both cases I was unable to establish a connection.

My code is mostly based on https://github.com/ginkage/wearmouse by google which I found thanks to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57137850) while I was looking for solutions to my own issue.

The issue is that there is no connection established after calling [`BluetoothHidDevice#connect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHidDevice#connect(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice)) which returns `true` as expected but then seemingly just times out.

When observing the log I just see the state switching between 1 (connecting) and 0 (disconnected):

```
D/BluetoothHidDevCallback: onConnectionStateChanged: device=[redacted MAC] state=1
D/BluetoothHidDevCallback: onConnectionStateChanged: device=[redacted MAC] state=0
...
```

I set up an android studio project where you just need to change `TARGET_DEVICE_NAME` inside of `MainActivity.java` to your target devices name and it should run out of the box (requires Android 9 Pie): https://github.com/domi1294/BluetoothHidDemo

Your devices need to be paired beforehand since it will check your paired devices for `TARGET_DEVICE_NAME` and attempt to connect to it when you press the button. If the connection was successful the button will instead send the string `"TestMessage"` to the target device.

If you run the app yourself and track `BluetoothHidDevCallback` in Logcat you should see it try to connect (state=1), disconnect (state=0) and repeat. It should change to state 2 which stands for connected and is what I expect to happen like it did when I tried the P10 --> S8+ connection.

Feel free to try connecting to a macOS device if you don't own a Windows pc, as I would like to know whether this is a Windows only problem or not.

Comment: Your device must be a server. That means that Windows PC establishes the connection to HID device. not HID device to Win 10 PC.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still new to Android programming and HID devices, but assuming it works like that why did it allow me to connect from my HID device to another Android device? Does Android handle it different or is this a Windows issue?

Comment: Yes, Android works different than Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is an open source project doing just that and it works great with PC too:
https://github.com/raghavk92/Kontroller