How to control Media operation via Bluetooth from One Android device to Another?
I need to create a android application similar to this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek&hl=en&gl=US but only the Media Controls Play/Pause Prev/Next and Volume. Tried Using AVRCP but it work's only with Android Things and not on Android Phone/tablets.
How to control Media Operations of the connected devices(Android Phone or tablet) Over Bluetooth.


Do you want to control a PC or another android phone?

Another android Phone @MichaelKotzjan

Maybe you can try the HID profile for your purpose. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917415/7473793
